# PHP form is sending blank email

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

I looked at other SO answers and I'm not getting an answer. I'm making a simple HTML form with an PHP script that sends an email. Simple. Except it's not working. Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contactform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Form</legend>
        <p><label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="first_name" class="text" required></p>
        <p><label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="last_name" class="text" required></p>
        <p><label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" class="text" required></p>
        <p><label>Message:</label><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30" class="message" required></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's the AJAX:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#contactform").submit(function(){
      $.get("contactsend.php", function(data){
        alert(data);
      })
      return false;
    })
</script>
```

And here's contactsend.php:

```
<?php 
$to = "shubhang.desai@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From: " . $from;
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    echo "Mail sent.";
} else {
    echo "An error occured. Try again later.";
}
```

?>

When click submit, the page is saying "Mail sent.", but the email goes through blank. I'm not sure why array _POST would be empty. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You've missed to send the form data to your server: [jQuery.get(url, data, success)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType)

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning on the fly. Where would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are not sent any data to server via ajax yet.

try with this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#contactform").submit(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contactsend.php",
        data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
</script>
```

Php:

```
<?php 
$to         = "shubhang.desai@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$from       = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject    = "Form submission";
$message    = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers    = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers   .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers   .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";

if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    echo "Mail sent.";
} else {
    echo "An error occured. Try again later.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$date = date( 'r' );

$phpversion = phpversion();

$headers = "From: ".$from."\nDate: ".$date."\nX-Mailer: PHP v".$phpversion."\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed to send the values from the form to your server.
You can use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get the values. It will transform them into a string with correctly encoded values.

```
$("#contactform").submit(function () {
    $.get("contactsend.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending any data along,try this

```
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#contactform").submit(function(){
var details = $(this).serialize();
  $.get("contactsend.php",details, function(data){
    alert(data);
  })
  return false;
})
</script>
```

The "serialize" function creates a query string automatically for a form,you can also serialize individual input fields.